# Primefaces TreeNode, showing Root Node in Vertical orientation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I am implementing a tree module using PrimeFaces framework. I want to show the Root Node in vertical orientation. I figured out that, with the same code, *Horizontal* orientation shows its Root Node, but *Vertical* orientation does not. Why is that? Is there anyway to show the Root Node in Vertical mode?

Vertical:

```
- Documents
- Videos
- Images
```

Horizontal:

```
               ----------- Images ---------- Travel.gif
               -
---- Root Node ----------- Videos ---------- Play.avi 
               -                   
               ----------- Documents ------- Expenses.doc
```

Here are the codes:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
</h:head>
<h:form>
<p:tree value="#{treeManagedBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" orientation="horizontal"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeManagedBean.singleSelectedTreeNode}">
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open"
                    collapsedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="image" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-image">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>                 
    <p:treeNode type="video" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-video">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeManagedBean.onNodeSelect}"></p:ajax>
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{treeManagedBean.onNodeUnSelect}"></p:ajax>
    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeManagedBean.onNodeExpand}"></p:ajax>
    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{treeManagedBean.onNodeCollapse}"></p:ajax>                                 
</p:tree>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeManagedBean {
// TreeNode instance
private TreeNode root;
private TreeNode singleSelectedTreeNode;
private TreeNode [] multipleSelectedTreeNodes;
private TreeNode [] checkboxSelectedTreeNodes;

public TreeManagedBean(){
    // This is the root node, so it's data is root and its parent is null
    this.root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root Node", null);
    // Create documents node
    TreeNode documents = new DefaultTreeNode("Documents", this.root);
    // Create document node
    TreeNode document01 = new DefaultTreeNode("document","Expenses.doc", documents);
    // Create images node
    TreeNode images = new DefaultTreeNode("Images", this.root);
    // Create image node
    TreeNode image01 = new DefaultTreeNode("image","Travel.gif", images);
    // Create videos node
    TreeNode videos = new DefaultTreeNode("Videos", this.root);
    // Create video node
    TreeNode video01 = new DefaultTreeNode("video","Play.avi", videos);
}

public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
    this.root = root;
}

public TreeNode getSingleSelectedTreeNode() {
    return singleSelectedTreeNode;
}

public void setSingleSelectedTreeNode(TreeNode singleSelectedTreeNode) {
    this.singleSelectedTreeNode = singleSelectedTreeNode;
}

public TreeNode[] getMultipleSelectedTreeNodes() {
    return multipleSelectedTreeNodes;
}

public void setMultipleSelectedTreeNodes(TreeNode[] multipleSelectedTreeNodes) {
    this.multipleSelectedTreeNodes = multipleSelectedTreeNodes;
}

public TreeNode[] getCheckboxSelectedTreeNodes() {
    return checkboxSelectedTreeNodes;
}

public void setCheckboxSelectedTreeNodes(TreeNode[] checkboxSelectedTreeNodes) {
    this.checkboxSelectedTreeNodes = checkboxSelectedTreeNodes;
}

public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event){
    System.out.println("Node Data ::"+event.getTreeNode().getData()+" :: Selected");
}

public void onNodeUnSelect(NodeUnselectEvent event){
    System.out.println("Node Data ::"+event.getTreeNode().getData()+" :: UnSelected");
}

public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event){
    System.out.println("Node Data ::"+event.getTreeNode().getData()+" :: Expanded");
}

public void onNodeCollapse(NodeCollapseEvent event){
    System.out.println("Node Data ::"+event.getTreeNode().getData()+" :: Collapsed");
}

public String printSelectedNodes(){
    System.out.println("Single Selection Is :: "+this.singleSelectedTreeNode.getData());
    for(TreeNode n : this.multipleSelectedTreeNodes){
        System.out.println("Multiple Selection Are :: "+n.getData());
    }
    for(TreeNode n : this.checkboxSelectedTreeNodes){
        System.out.println("CheckBox Selection Are :: "+n.getData());
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in my project on Primefaces 5.2. I just added fake root with null value and null parent. So you can do something like this:

```
    this.root = new DefaultTreeNode(null, null);
    TreeNode fakeRoot = new DefaultTreeNode("Root Node", root);
    TreeNode documents = new DefaultTreeNode("Documents", fakeRoot);
    TreeNode document01 = new DefaultTreeNode("document","Expenses.doc", documents);
    TreeNode images = new DefaultTreeNode("Images", fakeRoot);
    TreeNode image01 = new DefaultTreeNode("image","Travel.gif", images);
    TreeNode videos = new DefaultTreeNode("Videos", fakeRoot);
    TreeNode video01 = new DefaultTreeNode("video","Play.avi", videos);
```

And accordding to  [Primefaces's sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2/org/primefaces/component/tree/TreeRenderer.java#159) root node rendred only for not vertical tree so you can't change this behavior without editing sources:

```
    ...
    boolean vertical = tree.getOrientation().equals("vertical");
    ...
    if(!vertical && rowKey.equals("root")) {
        encodeHorizontalTreeNodeChildren(context, tree, tree.getValue(), tree.getClientId(context), null, tree.isDynamic(), tree.isCheckboxSelection());
    } else {
        ...
        if(vertical) {
              encodeTreeNodeChildren(context, tree, node, clientId, tree.isDynamic(), tree.isCheckboxSelection(), tree.isDroppable());
        } else {
              encodeHorizontalTreeNodeChildren(context, tree, node, tree.getClientId(context), rowKey, tree.isDynamic(), tree.isCheckboxSelection());
        }
   }
```